# When I build Unity3D. Somefile is 'Namespace error' at Plugins folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, namespaces

First I cannot English very well.

My development environment is

Windows 10 x64 //
Unity 5.6.6f2 //
Visual Studio 2015 Service Pack 3 //
.NetFrameWork 4.7

When I build Game. Somefile is 'Namespace error' at Plugins folder.
(RectClient, FacebookSDK, Itween and so on)

But building well my colleague at work's computer (We are same setting)

And good at 'UnityEditor'

So Plz Help me. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFGkk.png)

Answer (score -1):

So you get an namespace error with rectClient, fbSDK and iTween? Can u paste one error line here?
Did you update your unity version the last days?

Comment: Assets/Scripts/FBIAPManager.cs(264,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Do not update unity because company policy.

Comment: Try to fix it with Assets -> Reimport All.

If that doesn´t work, try deleting the Library\UnityAssemblies folder. After restarting Unity, the folder will appear and probably will fix your problem.

Comment: Also I read that people just updated to some newer version and that fixed the problem